# Prove that $|AB - \lambda I| = |BA - \lambda I|$.

Tags: matrices, determinant

Suppose that one has two matrices $A$, $B$. Then

> Prove that $$|AB - \lambda I| = |BA - \lambda I|,$$
>   where $|\cdot|$ denotes the determinant, $I$ - identity matrix and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

Note that $A$ and $B$ are **not** necessary invertible. For invertible matrices I easily found
$$|AB - \lambda I| = |B(AB - \lambda I)B^{-1}| = |BA - \lambda I|.$$

Comment: Note that the invertible matrices are dense in the set of matrices (for the topology induced by a norm).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm aware of three proofs. The first is the one you get by combining your argument with Marko's comment. The second is to show that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same non-zero eigenvalues with the same multiplicities. The third proof runs as follows. Set
\[
  M=\begin{pmatrix}I&A\\ B&I\end{pmatrix},\quad N=\begin{pmatrix}I&0\\-B&I\end{pmatrix}
\]
and then note that
\[
  MN=\begin{pmatrix}I-AB&A\\0&I\end{pmatrix},\quad NM=\begin{pmatrix}I&A\\0&I-BA\end{pmatrix}.
\]
Since $\det(MN)=\det(NM)$, the result follows.

One advantage of the third proof is that it works for matrices over a commutative ring.

Comment: @lhf Because $\det$ preserves mutliplication: $\det(MN)=\det(M)\det(N)=\det(N)\det(M)=\det(NM)$.

Comment: Could you please explain how $|I-AB|=|I-BA|$ is equivalent to the result?

Comment: @Itay: Replace $A$ by $\lambda^{-1}A$. (Note that $A$ And $B$ need not be square.)

Answer (score 5):

There is an old-fashioned proof depending only on the properties of determinants and minors.

(i) In $\det(xI-X)$ the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ is the sum of the principal $k\times k$ minors of $X$.

(ii) Let $X^{(k)}$ denote the matrix of $k\times k$ minors of $X$ for any square $X$. Then by a theorem sometimes called the Binet-Gauss Theorem we have that $(XY)^{(k)}=X^{(k)}Y^{(k)}$.

(iii) For any square matrices $X,Y$ we have $\text{tr}(XY)=\text{tr}(YX)$.

So the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ in $\det(xI-AB)$ is 
$$\text{tr}((AB)^{(k)})=\text{tr}(A^{(k)}B^{(k)})$$ whereas 
the coefficient of $x^{n-k}$ in $\det(xI-BA)$ is 
$$\text{tr}((BA)^{(k)})=\text{tr}(B^{(k)}A^{(k)})$$
and these are equal.