# How to show that $det(AB-xI)=det(BA-xI)$ ,for any $x\in \mathbb F$.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, characteristic-polynomial

There is a problem in Hoffmann Kunze:

Show that $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomials,where $A,B$ are both $n\times n$ matrices in $\mathbb F$.

If $A$ or $B$ is invertible it can be easy done:

$det(AB-xI).det(A)=det(ABA-xA)=det(A).det(BA-xI)$ and if $detA\neq 0$,we can cancel it to get our desired result but what about the case when both $detA $ and $detB$ are $0$.How to proceed in that case?

By the way the case $n=2$ is easy as $p_A(x)=x^2-tr(A)x+det(A)$ and so characteristic polynomial of $AB$ and $BA$ must be same as they have the same trace and same determinant.But this idea cannot be applied for higher order matrices.

Comment: If you know about exterior algebra, you can extend that $n=2$ argument to any $n$.

Comment: View the coefficients of $A$ and $B$ as variables, say $A = (a_{ij})$ and $B = (b_{ij})$. You then have $\det(AB - xI) = \det(BA - xI)$ as an identity over the field $F = \Bbb F(a_{11}, \dotsc, a_{nn}, b_{11}, \dotsc, b_{nn}, x)$, by what you already know: because $A$ is invertible over $F$.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2156210/prove-that-ab-lambda-i-ba-lambda-i) or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17831/sylvesters-determinant-identity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bit tricky way, but which it even can be applied when $A$ and $B$ are not square matrices, so $A$ is $n\times m$ and $B$ is $m\times n$, is the following:

Consider the identity of the product of matrices with dimensions $(n+m)\times (n+m)$: $$\begin{pmatrix} I_n & -A \\ B & I_m \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} I_n & 0 \\ B & I_m \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} I_n & -A \\ 0 & I_m+BA \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} I_n+AB & -A \\ 0 & I_m \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} I_n & 0 \\ B & I_m \end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, using the following result on the determinant of "block" triangular matrices 
$$\text{det}\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ B & C\end{pmatrix}=\text{det}(A)\text{det}(C)$$
we get that 
$$\text{det}(I_n+AB)=\text{det}(I_m+BA).$$

Finally, one gets from this that
$$(-x)^{m}\text{det}(AB-xI_n)=(-x)^{n} \text{det}(BA-xI_m).$$
which, in your case $n=m$, gives the result.

Answer (score 4):

How about this? introduce a new indeterminate $t$, and consider
$(A+tI)B-xI$ and $B(A+tI)-xI$. Over the extension field $\Bbb F(t)$ the matrix
$(A+tI)$ **is** invertible, so
$$\det((A+tI)B-xI)=\det(B(A+tI)-xI).$$
Both sides of this equation are elements of the polynomial ring $\Bbb F[x,t]$.
Now we can replace $t$ by $0$ to get
$$\det(AB-xI)=\det(BA-xI).$$

Comment: I do not want to use field or ring theory here because I have yet not studied rings and fields.Please give me a purely linear algebraic answer.

Comment: @ThomasShelby Its determinant is a nonzero element of $\Bbb F(t)$.